# Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar ночная тема стала дефолтной Kotlin Android

Tags: android

Проблема в том что запуская программу она сразу в темной теме, хотя по логике пользователь первый раз запуская программу должен видеть светлую тему а уж потом менять под себя.
Поковырявшись в коде пришел к тому что проблема скорее всего в color-night.
Так как если поменять цвета с color в color-night то программа запускает в начале светлую тему. Но такое решение как по мне не совсем правильное. Подскажите как можно это исправить.

Comment: мейби у вас на девайсе темная тема в настройках выставлена на данный момент, просто?)

Comment: Да! Именно в этом и оказалась проблема, хотя в приложении отключена   

    <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="q">false</item>

Видимо что то не так отключили)